# serialize class instance for comparison

Tags: python, serialization, version-control, pickle

I have an application which is working with projects. These projects are currently stored as pickles, generated with

```
cPickle.dump(project, open(filename, 'wb'), HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

These project files need to be diffable because they are used in a version control environment.
The problem is, if I serialize the exact same object, the pickle turns out different every time. 0 as protocol works, but I need the files to be smaller (they are around 12MB with protocol 0).

Comment: A diffable file is going to larger than a binary one. Might get a net gain by dumping with `HIGHEST_PROTOCOL` and then encoding the binary result into ascii hexadecimal (but it's doubtful. IMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I'm gonna post it here in case anyone has the same question in the future.

The solution is to do a deepcopy of the object directly before it's pickled.
That way the reference count which apparently causes the differences gets reset and the files turn out the same when using HIGHEST_PROTOCOL.
So instead of

```
cPickle.dump(instance, open(filename, 'wb'), HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

you need to do this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
cpy = deepcopy(instance)
cPickle.dump(cpy, open(filename, 'wb'), HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
cpy = None
```

That way the file size is reduced significantly while still maintaining comparability.